# How to remove the sibling node of XML

Tags: c#, xml

How to remove the sibling node of XML. I need to remove CreationDateTime value.
I am limited to XMLdocument in C#.

How to use say that i need to select the value element which is next to CreationDateTime Name element.

xmlDoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name == "Value").Remove();

```
<Mic><Attribute>
    <Name>CreatedBy</Name>
    <Value>MS</Value>
</Attribute>
<Attribute>
    <Name>CreationDateTime</Name>
    <Value>04/13/2018 19:45:38</Value>
</Attribute></Mic>
```

Comment: `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`?

Comment: `XmlDocument` does not have `Descendants` so your code will not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are limited to using `XmlDocument`, you need to get all the `Attribute` tags and then remove their last child (this is the Value tag).

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("YourFile.xml");

// Get all the Attribute tags
var atts = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Attribute");

// Traverse and remove the last child (this is the Value tag)
foreach (XmlNode thisElement in atts)
{
    thisElement.RemoveChild(thisElement.LastChild);
}
```